# How to exclude only one file in add in Git?

Tags: git

I need to exclude only one file when I add files for commit. Say my commit directory `..\Git_Folder` and I need to exclude only `Git_SubFolder/x.sdf`.

How to do that?

Comment: why don't you add that file to .gitignore file ??

Answer (score 3):

A quick way could be to `reset` that one file like this:

```
git add .
git reset x.sdf
```

This would bring the changes to x.sdf back to your working directory. To totally exclude that file from being staged by Git include it in your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Your answer is not current. it should be done via .gitignore

Comment: @codeWizard The original question didn't state that it was desired to permanently ignore that file... If it was only wanted to not stage that file during this operation my approach is a quick and easy solution.

Comment: By this way file is untracked. Still says error.. I decided to exclude that file because size of the file is very large. Now it becomes smaller. Still it contains old details. And complaint..

Comment: @Nisha what is the error message? When you say "exclude the file" did you simply not stage it or add it to .gitignore?

Comment: File Git_SubFolder/x.sdf is 120.31 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

Comment: @Nisha If you have already pushed that file to GitHub you may want to remove it from your history. See this page for information on that route: http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/03/06/ignoring-doesnt-remove-a-file.html

Answer (score 1):

several options:

#### .gitignore

Add the file to .gitignore file

```
// .gitignore content
x.sdf
```

---

#### assume-unchanged

use this on the file which you don't want git to track

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

---

Use this site to generate your desired ignore file
https://www.gitignore.io/

Comment: I added the following to .gitignore. But still it doesn't work
*.sdf

Comment: add  this to your file: `**/*.sfd`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the file extension to your `.gitignore` file.

A convenient way to tell which files you should naturally ignore is through [this site](https://www.gitignore.io/). Which will help you filter out files that shouldn't be included in the Repository for these project types.

Also see the official documentation for examples as provided [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Hope that helps!